# Image based Checkbox is checked but the values not added to text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all I thank everyone for helping me. I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript. I want to pass the check-box value to text field when it is checked. when I checked using the image in anchor it is not passing the values, but it does when checked checkbox directly.

Below is my live code, please check where I did mistake.

**Pretty checkbox code:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


            $('span.mktLblRight input').each(function(){
        $(this).next('label').andSelf().wrapAll('<p/>');
            });

                      $("li.mktLblRight").wrapAll('<span class="checkbox-align"/>');



        $("span.mktLblRight").addClass("checklist");
        $("span.checklist p").append('<a class="checkbox-select" href="#">Select</a><a class="checkbox-deselect" href="#">Cancel</a>');


        // code from here on is the same as Aaron Weyenberg
        $(".checklist .checkbox-select").click(
            function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
                $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").prop("checked","checked");
                this.checked = true;
            }
        );

        $(".checklist .checkbox-deselect").click(
            function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
                $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").removeProp("checked");
                this.checked = true;
            }
        );

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5euSB/109/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're programmatically changing the value of the input field with:

```
$(this).parent().find(":checkbox").removeProp("checked");
```

This doesn't trigger the change event. A quick solve is to just manually trigger the change with:

```
$(this).parent().find(":checkbox").removeProp("checked").trigger('change');
```

An update of your sample: http://jsfiddle.net/5euSB/111/

Comment: Thankd @jerrylow, you're code works perfectly in jsfiddle as I expected, but unfortunately it did't work on my live page.. Here's my page http://go.qlik.com/EMEA-program-test_Reg_Summer-Dummy.html

Comment: I just fixed it by updating the JavaScript. Now it works perfectly in my live page. Thanks alot @jerrylow